# Why does smartmatch return true when comparing array slices that should be different?

Tags: perl, smartmatch

The following script smart-matches slices of two arrays. At the start, both arrays are the same and I'm getting reasonable results. Then I change one of the arrays and smart-match two new slices, but it still says that the slices are identical. However, when I copy the slices into arrays, smart-matching the arrays shows that they are indeed different.

The script:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;
use diagnostics;

my @x = qw (one two);
my @y = qw (one two);
my @x_s;
my @y_s;

print "Before change: values are the same:\n";
@x_s = @x[0,1];
@y_s = @y[0,1];
print "\@x_s: @x_s\n";
print +(@x[0,1] ~~ @y[0,1]) ? "equal\n" : "not equal\n";
print +(@x_s ~~ @y_s) ? "equal\n" : "not equal\n";

$x[0]='three';

print "After change: values should be different:\n";
@x_s = @x[0,1];
@y_s = @y[0,1];
print "\@x_s: @x_s\n";
print +(@x[0,1] ~~ @y[0,1]) ? "equal\n" : "not equal\n";
print +(@x_s ~~ @y_s) ? "equal\n" : "not equal\n";
```

The output:

```
Before change: values are the same:
@x_s: one two
equal
equal
After change: values should be different:
@x_s: three two
equal
not equal
```

I'm using Perl 5.10.1, and this happens for both array slices and hash slices. Why does this happen?

Comment: Which version of Perl are you using? With `v5.14.2` I get `equal`, `equal` and `not equal`, `not equal`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looks like smart matching works in scalar context with slices.

Consider the following code pieces:

Your case:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

my @foo = (1,2);
my @bar = (3,4);
print @foo[1,2] ~~ @bar[1,2] ? "Equal\n" : "Not equal\n";
```

That's probably what you need:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

my @foo = (1,2);
my @bar = (3,4);
print [ @foo[1,2] ] ~~ [ @bar[1,2] ] ? "Equal\n" : "Not equal\n";
```

Answer (score 3):

The smart match operator `~~` does its magic for arrays, not for lists. An array slice is a list, not an array.

*Update:*

You can solve it just by enclosing your slices into brackets, since smart match automatically dereferences:

```
print +([@x[0,1]] ~~ [@y[0,1]]) ? "equal\n" : "not equal\n";
```

Comment: "An array slice is a list, not an array." - what?!

Answer (score 0):

*Originally posted by [askucins](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1108588/askucins)*

I ran a quick query in the Perl docs related to the different behaviour of that test vs. the Perl version and I found that this was fixed in Perl 5.13.5. See "Smart matching against array slices" in [perl5135delta](http://perldoc.perl.org/perl5135delta.html#Smart-matching-against-array-slices):

> Previously, the following code resulted in a successful match:
>
> ```
> my @a = qw(a y0 z);
> my @b = qw(a x0 z);
> @a[0 .. $#b] ~~ @b;
> ```
>
> This odd behaviour has now been fixed [[perl #77468](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/http:#%2frt.perl.org%2frt3%2f%2fPublic%2fBug%2fDisplay.html%3fid%3d77468)].